# How to broadcast using XMPP?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I'm building an XMPP based IM application on the iOS. I was wondering if there is a provision for broadcasting a message to all the users. This is different from the group chat mechanism which is still limited to N number of users. Say for example...The XMPP foundation broadcasts a message to all users that there is some change in the XEPs...SOmething like that? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, I'm curious too... why the down vote???!!! I think is better to ask if something is not clear instead vote down! This is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the support Lorenzo. I think I got the answer partially...Will be posting it shortly. Maybe somebody finds it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most XMPP server have a way to broadcast to all users, but this generally depends on the server. Openfire has a Broadcast module. ejabberd has a module call mod_announce.

Alternatively, depending on your need, you may want to look into XMPP pubsub. This is a publish and subscribe protocol that allows publishers to broadcast messages to subscribers.

Comment: Thanks MIckael for the response. I guess I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

There is a real time collaboration server licenced under the Open Source Apache License. Entitlted  `OpenFire`. It uses the XMPP protocol and can be managed easily via a web interface. This `OpenFire` server provides a plugin called `Broadcast` to all users and or groups. Again installation for the same is very well documented. Maybe this should do the trick. If this works for me, I will update my answer here.